# How to search data on a json array of values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have never used `json data` to store any values inside my database, now the situation prompted me to use that.

Below is my `json` format I'm storing that into MySQL database

```
{
    "wrestling_board": [{
        "Price": "400",
        "Quantity": "1",
        "Amount": "400"
    }],
    "sign_board": [{
        "Price": "200",
        "Quantity": "1",
        "Amount": "200"
    }],
    "total": [{
        "Price": null,
        "Quantity": null,
        "Amount": "600"   <-- total price
    }]
}
```

[**Here is MySQL Demo:**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27fd3c/3)

How to search all `results` `where total.amount > 3000`?

Comment: 1. that's a horrible way to store data as you are finding out 2. you must select all of the data, loop through, decode it and test for > 3000

Comment: What have you tried? We're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: If you are using mySQL 5.7 then you could use the JSON datatype to store the data and also retrieve it. See manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: @jeff, i'm using mySQL 5.7

Comment: You have invalid type for the column where you store JSON data. The column type should be JSON, not TEXT. Please rewrite your fiddle accordingly.

Comment: @olegsv, i have updated my datatype to `json` here is **demo:**http://rextester.com/NCNKO28286

Answer (score 1):

Update:
If your field is json, you can use a query like this:

```
select 
    customer_name,company_name,email,quotation_data
from 
    sent_quotation_data1
where 
    cast(                                             --> as you want to check numeric operator I use cast to unsigned
        (replace(                                     --> as your data is between " I use replace to remove them
            quotation_data->"$.total[0].Amount"       --> Here you can extract json data
        ,'"','')) as unsigned
    ) > 3000;
```

[**MySQL Fiddle Demo**](http://rextester.com/VPWK18090)

---

I think a way is using `REGEXP` like this:

```
select 
   customer_name,company_name,email,quotation_data 
from 
   sent_quotation_data
where 
   quotation_data REGEXP '"total":.+"Amount":"(3[0-9][0-9][1-9]|[4-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{4,})"';
```

[**MySQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27fd3c/29)

```
"total":                     --> Finding total between " then :
.+                           --> Some characters
"Amount":"                   --> Finding Amount between " then : then "
(                            --> start a combination
    3[0-9][0-9][1-9]         --> accepting range of 3001-3999
    |                        --> or
    [4-9][0-9]{3}            --> accepting range of 4000-9999
    |                        --> or
    [1-9][0-9]{4,}           --> accepting range of 10000-...
)                            --> end of combination
"                            --> following by "
```